# Infura Web Sockets doesn't work on Infura

Tags: web3js, events, infura, web3-providers, websocket

I have a problem with connecting via Websockets to Infura. I am listening on some events from my smart contract, so when some event is dispatched by calling some method from smart contract, I should catch that event and do some stuff inside callback. Actually this seems to work locally(localhost), so I am connecting to Infura via Websockets without problem and everything works fine.

The problem occurs when a backend is deployed on aws instance. So the WebSocket connection to that AWS instance cannot be done and the most strangest thing is that I don't get any errors. Here is the code:

```
const web3Socket = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws"));
...
...
...
let instance = await new web3Socket.eth.Contract(contractAbi, address);
 instance.events.transactionEvent({
        fromBlock: "latest"
    }, (error, event) => { console.log(event); })
        .on('data', async (event) => {
            // do some stuff
        })
        .on('changed', function(event){
            console.log('CHANGED');
            console.log(event);
            // remove event from local database
        })
        .on('error', console.error);
...
...
...
```

So actually `.on('error', console.error);` is not throwing any error for example connection lost or connection refused. Any tips/suggestions on what to try next or what can cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://infura.io/docs/gettingStarted/chooseaNetwork), the web3 provider URL should look something like:

> wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID